# RLIKE expression giving 'mismatched input' error

Tags: sql, regex, hive, redash, rlike

I am querying a Hive table through Redash. I have a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(id AS INT) as id,
    COUNT(sales) AS num_sales
FROM 
    sales_table
WHERE 
    id RLIKE '\d*'
GROUP BY 
    id
```

I am trying to select only IDs which are a string of digits, hence the `WHERE` clause. This is giving me this error:

```
Error running query: line 42:20: mismatched input 'RLIKE'. Expecting: '%', '*', '+', '-', '.', '/', 'AT', '[', '||', <expression>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
WHERE id RLIKE '^[0-9]+$'
```

Note that the above expression ensures that `id` is made of digits only (and non-empty). You original regexp was checking if `id` contained *0 to n* digits (that's what the `*` quantifier means): this is way to permissive, as it would basically allow anything that is not null.

Answer (score 0):

1)

Hive regex requires double escaping

also, for full match you should use anchoring, therefore -

```
id RLIKE '^\\d+$'
```

if empty string is also an option then -

```
id RLIKE '^\\d*$'
```

2)
You can take the opposite approach and search for strings that does not contain a non-digit -

```
id  NOT RLIKE '\\D'
```

3)
In Hive a false casting results in null (and not an exception) therefore you could use -

```
cast(id as int) is not null
```

or

```
int(id) is not null
```

Answer (score -1):

In Hive, the code should compile with either `REGEXP` or `RLIKE`.  However, your regular expression does not do what you want.  You want:

```
WHERE id RLIKE '^[0-9]*$'
```

That is, *all* characters are digits, rather than it just containing a single digit.  Well, actually, your version would match *any* string, because the digit is optional.

Comment: Hive regex requires double escaping